# How to change route without re-rendering in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created a filter that when I clicked confirmed button changes url.

For example, When I clicked page 1 and place type guesthouse in paris, url looks like this below.

```
http://localhost3000/findstay?page=1&per=10&place_type=guest_house&city=paris
```

Now I want to changed the result when url changed. Suppose when I manually changed query params like below, filter should also changed.

```
http://localhost3000/findstay?page=1&per=10&place_type=hotel&city=newYork
```

In order to do this.  I created a file name **findstay** in pages folder and created **findstay-filter** component inside of components folder.

```
import React from "react";
import FindstayFilter from "@/components/findstay/findstay-filter";

interface IFindstayProps { };

const Findstay: React.FC<IFindstayProps> = () => {
  return <FindstayFilter />;
};

export default Findstay;
```

All the logic I have explained are written inside of **FindstayFilter** component.

And this is the code that pushses url when **FindstayFilter** is rendered.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const { city, page, per, placeType } = query;
    const _page = parseInt(page || 1 as any);
    const _city = city || state.cityState; // paris
    const _placeType = placeType || "";

    router.push({
      pathname: `/findstay`,
      query: {
        page: _page,
        per: 10,
        plage_type: _placeType,
        city: _city,
      }
    }, undefined,
      { shallow: true })

    const initialRender = {
      page: _page,
      placeType: _placeType,
      city: _city,
    }
    
    searchAvailableBookingDays(initialRender).then(res => res.json().then(value => setData(value)));
  }, []);
```

As you can see I used **{shallow: true}** option and url does not changes only query params are changed. However when I changed one of queries manually (city=paris -> city=newYork), component re-renders  and reset query params that I pushes when component renders first time.

Why shallow option is not working?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? We are experiencing the same behaviour.

Comment: @roka Check out my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the meantime we solved this similar to your response with `window.location.replaceState`.  :)  Totally forgot about this question here, would’ve added it otherwise, too.

Answer (score 10):

The `shallow` option is working. Its goal is to not let your browser navigate away. But it definitely triggers a state update, which triggers the re-render.

Surely, you've had occasions where you really need it to trigger that state update so you can use updated query param values.

Now, how do you update the URL without triggering a re-render? You use `window.history`, not Next router.

So, instead of this:

```
router.push({
      pathname: `/findstay`,
      query: {
        page: _page,
        per: 10,
        plage_type: _placeType,
        city: _city,
      }
    }, undefined,
      { shallow: true })
```

You would do this:

```
const newUrl = `/findstay?page=${_page}&per=10&place_type=_placeType&city=_city`

window.history.replaceState({ ...window.history.state, as: newUrl, url: newUrl }, '', newUrl)
```

It's ugly, but it works as expected. A really nice way to keep your route synced with your state.

I'd recommend you turn it into a utility function.

Comment: Simple way to achieve this, however, is there any alternative solution? Because I did not find any. Which is strange, thought Next.js is going to have something to deal with this in 2023.

Comment: Next.js is unquestionably dominant in the marketplace, but the developers still make mistakes from time to time, such as letting issues like this go unchecked for long periods of time.

This is not unique to Next.js, I find it hard to find tooling where there are no pain points or mistakes made by it's developers.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely seeing re-renders caused by state changes caused by `useRouter` 's state changing due to the "new" route.

An easy fix for this is to use `Router` instead of `useRouter`. Both function the same as `useRouter` is just a `RouterContext` to the Class:

useRouter: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/client/router.ts#L127-L129

Router: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/next-server/lib/router/router.ts#L505

Be aware that you'll need to change the parent components in your component tree to also use `Router` instead of `useRouter`.

Comment: the links in this response are now broken